# Stretching the image for different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, background, size

I wasn't too sure on what to search for my answer. Basically I have a design made, and the header can be seen [here](http://cl.ly/2o1v2H3B2B2w2k423B3Q).

The width of the document there is 1200. I can get hold of a bigger version for a width of up to 2560, but how should I go about using the image? Should I use CSS media queries and use different images for a certain screen size? Note: this isn't a mobile site design; I just need to function with all computer screens.

I'm sorry if this has been asked/answered before but as I said I wasn't 100% sure on what to search.

Comment: can you give some code in jsfiddle.net for help you

Comment: Hi Aram, I haven't started coding yet as this is the first part of the site, I just wanted some input.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the height and the width in %, and use one image. But i think you should use different images for the different size, because it's mobile, and if you can avoid to your users to load unnecessary data, do it.

Comment: Hey julesanchez, I think you mis-read. This site will not be for mobile, only computers :-) So just define the height and apply width as 100%? And perhaps use the large 2560 width image for it all and the CSS/HTML will automatically scale it to the desired width?

Comment: Hi, yes , sorry i red ' site is for mobile'. So in that case use 100% for width and height

Answer (score 0):

If it's a foreground image, then just use percentage widths. If it's a background image, you can use the `background-size` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [script](http://www.warriorforum.com/website-design/10031-script-load-different-css-depending-screen-resolution.html). It basically identifies the screen size and then loads appropriate css where you can use images that match the screen.

Changing background size in % is not a good option (easiest though) because browser will load full image (largest) anyway and then rescale it to match the size. This could degrade your page loading performance if you use large images.

Comment: Here is another image just so you guys can see; http://cl.ly/0Q37000u3m3z0j3E2116

The height will always be the same but obviously the width will differ between screen size. So I will be applying the background to a  <header></header> tag :)